# How to match unicode by writing system (SCRIPT)?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, unicode

Sorry for the bad English, using google translator

What regular expression (REGEX) will be able to correspond by script type? Example: `\p{Script: Latin} | \p{Script: Zyyy} | \p{Script: Greek}`

The main objective is to use the expression to check string in PHP and JAVASCRIPT. But it would be ideal to be functional in all languages.

And also required the statement to be able to find negative cases, example:
`[^a] | [^\p{Script: Latin}]`

On the website below, has the ranges list for each SCRIPT. But turn it into a single string has caused divergence in particular Zyyy script that matches everything, and should not.

- http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/Scripts.txt

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Complementing ... "Zyyy" on the site above is the nickname for "Common"

Comment: `\p{Script: Latin}` these aren't supported on Javascript. http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html

Comment: Thank Mouser. This site you provided says that \p{Common} or \p{Greek} works on both PHP and JAVASCRIPT with XRegExp. Although the ideal would be something comprehensive that did not require plugins, that already helps me. Tested here in chrome and firefox and it worked. Thank U.http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#script

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a single Unicode-aware regular expression, you may not want to pull in the entire [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) library + its Unicode plugin for just that. An alternative solution would be to use a build script that compiles the regular expression using [Regenerate](https://mths.be/regenerate) and [the Unicode data packages](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/unicode-7.0.0).

Here’s what that would look like in Node.js:

```
var regenerate = require('regenerate');

// Latin script
var Latin = require('unicode-7.0.0/scripts/Latin/code-points');
// Greek script
var Greek = require('unicode-7.0.0/scripts/Greek/code-points');

var set = regenerate() // Start with an empty set.
    .add(Latin) // Add Latin script code points.
    .add(Greek) // Add Greek script code points.

// Print the result.
console.log(set.toString());
```

Run `npm install regenerate unicode-7.0.0`, and then run this script as follows:

```
node generate-regular-expression.js
```

It prints the following output:

```
[A-Za-z\xAA\xBA\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\u02B8\u02E0-\u02E4\u0370-\u0373\u0375-\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0384\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03E1\u03F0-\u03FF\u1D00-\u1D2A\u1D2C-\u1D77\u1D79-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FDD-\u1FEF\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFE\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u2126\u212A\u212B\u2132\u214E\u2160-\u2188\u2C60-\u2C7F\uA722-\uA787\uA78B-\uA78E\uA790-\uA7AD\uA7B0\uA7B1\uA7F7-\uA7FF\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB5F\uAB64\uAB65\uFB00-\uFB06\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A]|\uD800[\uDD40-\uDD8C\uDDA0]|\uD834[\uDE00-\uDE45]
```

This can be used directly as part of a regular expression literal.

The main advantage of this approach is that you’ll never have to tweak the regular expression manually. Instead, you can just change the script that generates it by adding or removing some symbols, then running it again. The code of the script is much more readable and maintainable than any regular expression, IMHO. Also, the output is as compact as possible: rather than introducing an entire library as a run-time dependency, you just insert a single regular expression literal.